# storing and retrieving tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm making website with asp.net (c#) and sql server database

I want to save data in a hierarchical database to be as tree and counting no of child nodes to specific parent

Can any body help me?

Comment: It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue.

Comment: Can you at least share the Database structure?

Comment: You may want to try Google, there are many walk through tutorials - even some on Microsoft's site!

Answer (score 1):

you have to store data in parent child format something like

table 1
columns.
Element ParentId

so while retrieving
first retrieve element with null parent id.
then retrieve elements which have already rendered element as their parent Id
and so on..